# A* with jump point search slower than regular A* in XNA?

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, xna, a-star

**Edit:**

In order to help viewers of this question become answerers, I'll note that the problem seems to be in the diagonal case of Jump. What in that method, when run recursively, could cause a slowdown?

**End of edit.**

In a XNA game I'm developing I use A* + JPS algorithm to navigate over a uniform square grid each frame. I learned about JPS [here](http://zerowidth.com/2013/05/05/jump-point-search-explained.html) and [here](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-speed-up-a-pathfinding-with-the-jump-point-search-algorithm--gamedev-5818).  However, when I run the game, the frame rate drops. The frame rate is so low that it makes the game unplayable. Removing the call to the Jump Point Search 'jump', and going with regular A* instead, fixed the problem for large enough square sizes. According to the article, JPS is supposed to be greatly more efficient than regular A*. The cause of the slowdown seems to be the two calls to Jump in the "Diagonal Case" (line 15-29 of the Jump method).

Obviously, there must be something wrong/inefficient in my implementation. But what is it?

**Code:**

The Jump method is the implementation of the JPS recursive jump function.

```
    public Vector2? Jump(Vector2 current, Vector2 direction, Vector2 start, Vector2 end)
    {
        // Position of new node we are going to consider:
        Vector2 next = current + direction * SquareSize;

        // If it's blocked we can't jump here
        if (IsBlocked(next))
            return null;

        // If the node is the goal return it
        if (next.X == end.X && next.Y == end.Y) 
            return next;

        // Diagonal Case   
        if (direction.X != 0 && direction.Y != 0) 
        {
            Vector2 horizontalBehind = current - new Vector2(direction.X * SquareSize, 0);
            Vector2 verticalBehind = current - new Vector2(0, direction.Y * SquareSize);
            if (IsBlocked(horizontalBehind) || IsBlocked(verticalBehind))
            {
                return current;
            }
            // Check in horizontal and vertical directions for forced neighbors
            // This is a special case for diagonal direction
            if (Jump(next, new Vector2(direction.X, 0), start, end) != null || Jump(next, new Vector2(0, direction.Y), start, end) != null)
            {
                return current;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Horizontal case
            if (direction.X != 0)
            {
                Vector2 topBehind = current - new Vector2(direction.X * SquareSize, SquareSize);
                Vector2 above = current - new Vector2(0, SquareSize);
                Vector2 bottomBehind = current + new Vector2(-direction.X * SquareSize, SquareSize);
                Vector2 below = current + new Vector2(0, SquareSize);
                if (IsBlocked(topBehind) || IsBlocked(above) || IsBlocked(bottomBehind) || IsBlocked(below))
                {
                    return current;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Vector2 leftBehind = current - new Vector2(SquareSize, direction.Y * SquareSize);
                Vector2 left = current - new Vector2(SquareSize, 0);
                Vector2 rightBehind = current + new Vector2(-SquareSize, direction.Y * SquareSize);
                Vector2 right = current - new Vector2(SquareSize, 0);
                if (IsBlocked(leftBehind) || IsBlocked(left) || IsBlocked(rightBehind) || IsBlocked(right))
                {
                    return current;
                }
            }
        }
        // If forced neighbor was not found try next jump point
        return Jump(next, direction, start, end);
     }

    #endregion
}
```

Navigate is the method that implements A*, from the 'start' parameter to the 'end' Parameter.

PriorityQueue is a generic implementation based on [this article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2012/11/01/Priority-Queues-with-C.aspx?Page=1). It's Enqueue and Dequeue methods have O(log2(n)) complexity.

```
    public Vector2? Navigate(Vector2 start, Vector2 end)
    {
        PriorityQueue<float, Vector2> openSet = new PriorityQueue<float, Vector2>();
        List<Vector2> closedSet = new List<Vector2>(10);
        Dictionary<Vector2, Vector2> cameFrom = new Dictionary<Vector2, Vector2>(10);
        Dictionary<Vector2, float> gScores = new Dictionary<Vector2, float>(10);
        gScores[start] = 0;
        openSet.Enqueue(H(start, end), start);
        while (openSet.Count != 0)
        {
            Vector2 current = openSet.Dequeue().Value;
            if (WorldMap.InSquare(current) == WorldMap.InSquare(end))
                return ReconstructPath(cameFrom, current, start);
            List<Vector2> neighbours = WorldMap.GetNeighbours(current, start, end);
            closedSet.Add(current);
            foreach(Vector2 neighbour in neighbours)
            {
                if (closedSet.Contains(neighbour))
                    continue;
                float tenativeGScore = gScores[current] + Vector2.Distance(current, neighbour);
                if(!gScores.ContainsKey(neighbour) || gScores[neighbour] > tenativeGScore)//Discover a new node || Find a better path to a node
                {
                    cameFrom[neighbour] = current;
                    gScores[neighbour] = tenativeGScore;
                    float fScore = tenativeGScore + H(neighbour, end);//Calculate F.
                    openSet.Enqueue(fScore, neighbour);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

GetNeighbours is a method that returns the neighbours of the node 'vector'.
A* version:

```
    public List<Vector2> GetNeighbours(Vector2 point, Vector2 start, Vector2 end)
    {
        Vector2[] directions = new Vector2[8];
        List<Vector2> neighbours = new List<Vector2>(8);
        directions[0] = Vector2.UnitX;//right
        directions[1] = -Vector2.UnitX;//left
        directions[2] = Vector2.UnitY;//down
        directions[3] = -Vector2.UnitY;//up
        directions[4] = Vector2.UnitX + Vector2.UnitY;//down right
        directions[5] = -Vector2.UnitX + Vector2.UnitY;//down left
        directions[6] = Vector2.UnitX - Vector2.UnitY;//up right
        directions[7] = -Vector2.UnitX - Vector2.UnitY;//up left
        foreach(Vector2 direction in directions)
        {
            Vector2 neighbour = point + direction * SquareSize;
            if (!IsBlocked(neighbour))
                neighbours.Add(neighbour);
        }
        return neighbours;
    }
```

Jump Point Search version:

```
    public List<Vector2> GetNeighbours(Vector2 point, Vector2 start, Vector2 end)
    {
        Vector2[] directions = new Vector2[8];
        List<Vector2> neighbours = new List<Vector2>(8);
        directions[0] = Vector2.UnitX;//right
        directions[1] = -Vector2.UnitX;//left
        directions[2] = Vector2.UnitY;//down
        directions[3] = -Vector2.UnitY;//up
        directions[4] = Vector2.UnitX + Vector2.UnitY;//down right
        directions[5] = -Vector2.UnitX + Vector2.UnitY;//down left
        directions[6] = Vector2.UnitX - Vector2.UnitY;//up right
        directions[7] = -Vector2.UnitX - Vector2.UnitY;//up left
        foreach(Vector2 direction in directions)
        {
        //The only difference between this GetNeighbours and the other one 
        //is that this one calls Jump here.
            Vector2? jp = Jump(point + direction * SquareSize, direction, start, end);
            if (jp != null)
                neighbours.Add((Vector2)jp);
        }
        return neighbours;
    }
```

InSqaure is a method that returns the Vector2 that represents the square a Vector2 is in. It has O(1) complexity.

IsBlocked is a method that checks if a Vector2 is inside the map or not, and also it is in a blocked square ("blocked" means a square that has an obstacle in it). It has O(log2(n)) complexity.

**Additional Information:**

- I currently only checked this in situations where there are no obstacles between the goal and the start point. This means the JPS algorithm only expands 1 square. Meanwhile, the regular A* expands 8 to find a path from (100, 100) to (0, 0) but 2325 squares when finding the distance between (100, 100) to (-800, -580). In that last case, there is a noticable frame rate drop that makes the game almost unplayable.
- Frame rate is unlocked.
- There is no visible stutter in grids with less than about 1200 squares, the game has a slight, acceptable frame rate drop up to about 1600.

If there's need for any more information I will provide it happily,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In my game I use A* to tridimensional pathfinding. This requires more processing time, but the implementation is built in such a way that it is almost invisible.

```
        public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (calculating && openSet.Count > 0 && calculatingStep < 240)
            PathfindingStep(navDestination, navAccurancyFactor);
        else calculating = false;//...
    }
```

FixedUpdate call 50 times per second.

```
       private void PathfindingBegin(Vector3 destination)
    {
        navAccurancyFactor = (1 + (Vector3.Distance(walkerTransform.position, destination) / (accurancy * 5)));
        navDestination = destination;
        calculatingStep = 0;
        calculating = true;
        closedSet = new List<PathNode>();
        openSet = new List<PathNode>();
        Vector3 startPos;
        if (path.Count > 0)
            startPos = path.Last();
        else
            startPos = walkerTransform.position;
        // Шаг 2.
        PathNode startNode = new PathNode()
        {
            Position = startPos,
            CameFrom = null,
            PathLengthFromStart = 0,
            HeuristicEstimatePathLength = GetHeuristicPathLength(walkerTransform.position, destination)
        };
        openSet.Add(startNode);
    }
```

Call PathfindingBegin to start and next calls PathfindingStep onse per frame to build path.

```
        private void PathfindingStep(Vector3 destination, float accuracyFactor)
    {
        calculatingStep++;
        PathNode currentNode;
        // Шаг 3.
        currentNode = openSet.OrderBy(node => node.EstimateFullPathLength).First();
        // Шаг 4.
        if (Vector3.Distance(currentNode.Position, destination) <= accurancy * accuracyFactor)
        {
            PathfindingComplete(CollapsePath(GetPathForNode(currentNode)).ToArray());
            return;
        }
        // Шаг 5.
        openSet.Remove(currentNode);
        closedSet.Add(currentNode);
        // Шаг 6.
        List<PathNode> neighbours = GetNeighbours(currentNode, destination, accuracyFactor);
        foreach (PathNode neighbourNode in neighbours)
        {
            // Шаг 7.
            if (closedSet.Count(node => node.Position == neighbourNode.Position) > 0)
                continue;
            PathNode openNode = openSet.Find(node => node.Position == neighbourNode.Position);
            // Шаг 8.
            if (openNode == null)
                openSet.Add(neighbourNode);
            else if (openNode.PathLengthFromStart > neighbourNode.PathLengthFromStart)
            {
                // Шаг 9.
                openNode.CameFrom = currentNode;
                openNode.PathLengthFromStart = neighbourNode.PathLengthFromStart;
            }
        }
    }
```

At end call PathfindingComplete to apply path. Or not if destination unavalable.

```
        private void PathfindingComplete(Vector3[] pathPoints)
    {
        if (pathPoints != null)
        {
            status = DriverStatus.Navigating;
            foreach (Vector3 x in pathPoints)
            {
                //Debug.Log(x);
                path.Enqueue(x);
            }
            BuildPathArrows();
        }
        calculating = false;
    }
```

P.S. All project we can find at https://github.com/DaniilChikish/SpaceComander

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating not in one frame, but in several. And use deep profiling to find performance leak.

Comment: Could you please add sample code for better understanding